# Build .so files for opencv-android instead of .a files

Tags: opencv, shared-libraries, static-libraries, android

I am building opencv for Android using steps provided in this link: [OpenCV on Android - Silverglint](http://silverglint.com/opencv-on-android/). But after completion of the all the steps, I got multiple .a files instead of a single .so files.

How can I build .so file from .a files. If not, how can I use these multiple .a files in my android code (How can I import those?) ?

Comment: read the link you provided `Configure the build
sh ./scripts/cmake_android_arm.sh .This creates a build directory and runs a CMake command to populate the directory with a particular configuration of OpenCV.
You can edit this script (or pass it parameters that override any defined in the script itself) if you want a different configuration. For example:”-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON” –  if you want shared libs, instead of the default dynamic libs.`

Comment: @JonGoodwin Thanks. I missed that point. It worked. There is one more thing I would like to ask. The `scripts` directory has only three file for android i.e. `cmake_android_arm.sh`, `cmake_android_mips.sh` and `cmake_android_x86.sh`. Any idea I can I build for other arch? I tied changing arch name in these files but it throws incompatibility error.

Comment: this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/61240/opencv-2411-ndk-arm64-v8a-x86_64/) should help.